# Akka Tcp bound message usage

Tags: scala, tcp, akka

I am writing a Tcp client server. 
The server actor is created. In the constructor, it binds to an IP and a random port

I send the server actor an initial message to start communicating.
However this initial message is received Before the server actor receives Bound message.

Is there any way that I receive the Bound message before the server receives my initial message?
server constructor code

```
ServerActor extends Actor with ActorLogging
{
    var myAddress:InetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(hostName,0)
    val options:List[akka.io.Inet.SocketOption] = List():::List(Tcp.SO.ReuseAddress(true)):::List(Tcp.SO.ReceiveBufferSize(65535))
      manager ! Bind(self, myAddress,1,options) 

    def receive = {
        case b @ Bound(addr) => println(addr)
        myAddress = addr
        case c @ Connected(remoteAddress,localAddress) => 
          log.info("Client Connected. Remote: {} Local: {}", remoteAddress, localAddress)
          remoteConnection = sender()
          remoteConnection ! Register(self)

        case CommandFailed(_: Bind) =>
          log.error("Binding Command Failed. Exiting.")
          context stop self      

        case mRegisterMessage: RegisterMessage =>
          {

              //create register response and send it back
              val mRegisterResponseMessage = new RegisterResponseMessage(true, "IPv4", myAddress.getHostString, myAddress.getPort)
              sender() ! RegisterResponseMessage

          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/index.html#akka.actor.Stash

You can redefine `preStart` method and firstly do

```
context.become({ case b @ Bound(addr) =>
 ...
 unstashAll() 
 context.unbecome()})
```

All messages will be stashed and only `Bound` message will be processed. Then when a message will be received you will switch to standard `receive` and all messages will be received by your handler.